# Importing external library into Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, typescript-typings

New to Angular 2. Using Angular-CLI. I haven't imported an external library before. So far, I've installed Leafletjs via `npm install leaflet --save` and typings via `npm install @types/leaflet --save`. Now I just need to know how to import them for use in my component. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You simple import the component from leaflet that you want to use. Here is an example that uses "Map":

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Map } from 'leaflet'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    map: Map;
    title = 'app works!';

    constructor() {
        this.map....
    }
}
```

Look inside the node_modules\@types\leaflet\index.d.ts to see what you can import.

You can also check out this starter: https://github.com/haoliangyu/angular2-leaflet-starter